# jQuery validation to prevent keypress for username

Tags: jquery

Need jQuery validation code to allow user to type only char `[a-zA-Z]`,
  with min of 4 char and max of 15 character's, with one space allowed

Eg: Sakshi Jain

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reg_name').keyup(function() {
      var $th = $(this);
      $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, function(str) {
        return '';
      }));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Just so you know the example username you have entered is 11 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this, remove the unwanted characters first (like you were already doing, but allow spaces at this point)

Once you've only got characters you allow then check the length, if its lower than 4 or higher than 10 then validate it to an error (you could also do this on the `onvalidate` event as well).

Once you're good at this point then split the value of the input by spaces and check the length of the newly created array.

An example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayrk6cnm/) is here.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#reg_name').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);

        // Remove invalid characters (include spaces in the value chars, we will remove later)
        $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\ ]/g, function(str) 
        { return ''; } ) );

        // Check for the the username length
        if ($(this).val().length > 10 || $(this).val().length < 4)
        {
            $(this).removeClass('good').addClass('error');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('error').addClass('good');            
        }

        var s = $(this).val().split(' ');

        // if there are more than 1 spaces (2 elements in the array 's')
        if (s.length > 2)
        {
            $(this).removeClass('good').addClass('error');
        }
    });    
});
```